# Train loss value to consider convergence

Tags: regression, neural-networks, loss-functions

I am training a fully connected NN with 4 hidden layers for a task of regression of two rational target values, Using MSE loss.

My problem is determining whether the training process succeed, that is, whether I achieve convergence. The issue is that the numerical values I use to train the netwok are quite small - both input and output (but I assume the significant influence is of the label).

They are having values around 1e-4, the initial train loss is around 1e-3 and after about 10K epochs it decreses to 1e-7.
Is there any practice that regulate the values for having better insights? I assume it depends on a value which I determine is enough for my propose but I'm not sure how to decide with such low values.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute loss values don't matter when you want to know whether they are converging. You should look at the relative change of the loss value. Is the loss still dropping by 1% every 1K iterations? Then you might want to continue training.

Comment: Hi, thanks, you're right, I probably missmatched the terminology, but how do I determine whether the network succeed to fit the data or not? i.e. what loss value do I need to aim to in order to consider the loss after convergence as good enough with respect to the values of the data i'm training on. Thanks again.

Comment: "Good enough" seems very subjective, it depends on what you decide is good enough.

Comment: Yes, well the question is how do I get a sence of what is good enough for my propse, when all the values I get are very small. I wonderd if there are any practices like normalizing input, converting the output or using other loss functions to get more regularized values or if there is any practice to get a sence if the loss value after convergence points on a good process that the network predicts. Thanks

Comment: You could look at other metrics, such as mean error. Those are probably more informative than the loss value.